# Refreshing a materialized view in postgresql after a specific time

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have made a materialized view from a table named "table1". the table "table1" gets updated with a huge amount of data every 5 days. I need to now refresh the materialized view 2 hours after the table1 is changed. How do i achieve this? I found some answers regarding cronjob, pgadmin. I tried using a trigger function but i am stuck how do i execute it after a specific time after there is update to the table? Could someone help me out? A small rough example will be sufficient, i am kind of new to the database and all.

Comment: There is no reliable way to do that with database tecniques.

Comment: So, how do i do that? cronjob?

Comment: Yes, either external via cron or via extensions: 1) [pg_cron](https://www.citusdata.com/blog/2016/09/09/pgcron-run-periodic-jobs-in-postgres/) 2) [pg_timetable](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/products/pg_timetable/). Full disclosure I have not used either of the extensions so I don't know how effective they are.

Comment: +1 for pg_cron. However , accoring to OP's specification, you would need to know the end time of the update.

Comment: I would have the job that does the massive data modification refresh the materialized view.

Comment: @VynlJunkie, a modification of Laurenz Albe's idea would be to have the data script set an end time in a file or table then have the scheduler check that periodically and when the proper interval of time elapsed do the materialized view refresh.

Comment: Ok, i had an idea. i used node-cron library to refresh the materialized view. I searched and found out an api that gives the end of the 5 days in UNIX seconds. the cron task is scheduled for every hour, gets the end time from api, and it checks if the difference of end time and current time is smaller than 4 days and 20 hours and refreshes accordingly. is it fine?

Comment: https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/development/pgagent.html

Comment: If it does what you want then it is fine.